# Building cx_Oracle: limits.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am building cx_Oracle 5.3 on a Red Hat machine.

I run

```
python setup.py build
```

and receive the following error message:

```
In file included from /xy/Anaconda3/include/python3.5m/Python.h:11:0,
                 from src/cx_Oracle.c:17:
/usr/include/limits.h:125:26: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

However, limits.h does indeed exist with read permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4596 Jan 28  2016 /usr/include/limits.h
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

Comment: did you install python-dev ?

Comment: Ah, thanks. That's worth a try.